# PHP with DOMXPath - Sum values after selection of items

Tags: php, domxpath

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="wanted-list">
    <div class="headline"></div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="length">1100</div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="status">
            <img src="xxxx" alt="open">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry mark">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="length">800</div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="status">
            <img src="xxxx" alt="open">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="length">2300</div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="status">
            <img src="xxxx" alt="closed">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select only the items that are 'open', so I do:

```
$doc4 = new DOMDocument();
$doc4->loadHtmlFile('http://www.whatever.com');
$doc4->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath4 = new DOMXPath($doc4);
$elements4 = $xpath4->query("//div[@class='wanted-list']/div/div[5]/img[@alt='open']");
```

Now, if I'm not mistaken, we have isolated the 'open' items we wanted. Now, I need to get the 'length' values, and **sum them to make a total length** so I can echo it. I've spent several hours trying different solutions and researching, but I haven't found anything similar. Can you guys help?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED** the wrong div's, sorry.

Comment: Here's a way I ran this not using the `xpath` and corrected the HTML (divs are mis-closed, making HTML invalid).... https://eval.in/503044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean for the calculations all to be done in the xsl or whether you are just wanting the sum of the lengths to be available to you in php, however this captures and sums the lengths. As noted by @Chris85 in the comment - the html is invalid - there are spare closing `div` tags within each entry ~ presumably the image is supposed to be a child of `div.status`? If that is so the below would need slight modification when trying to target the correct parent. That said, I received no warnings from `DOMDocument` whilst parsing it but better to fix than ignore!

```
$strhtml='
<div class="wanted-list">
    <div class="headline"></div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="length">1100</div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="status">
            <img src="xxxx" alt="open">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry mark">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="length">800</div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="status">
            <img src="xxxx" alt="open">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="length">2300</div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="status">
            <img src="xxxx" alt="closed">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml( $strhtml );/* alternative to loading a file directly */
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);               
$col=$xp->query('//img[@alt="open"]');/* target the nodes with the attribute you need to look for */
/* variable to increment with values found from DOM values */
$length=0;

foreach( $col as $n ) {/* loop through the found nodes collection */
    $parent=$n->parentNode->parentNode;/* corrected here to account for change in html layout ~ get the suitable parent node */

    /* based on original code, find value from particular node */
    $length += $parent->childNodes->item(5)->nodeValue; 
}
echo 'Length:'.$length;
```

Comment: Chris85 and @RamRaider, those misclosed div's are my fault, I've corrected them. I tried to simplify the original html code. My idea is to get the sum of the lengths in the php and do it via DOMXPath, I need to learn how to deal with different situations, since I have to retrieve data from more than 5,000 different sources. Some are pretty easy to deal with, but others are difficult for my poor programming skills. It would be great to know if there's a good DOMXPath tutorial, I find the manual difficult to find your way through it.

Comment: your code works perfectly, I was adapting it the wrong way. Thank you very much. May I ask you to give a little detail on your code? Or can you point me to any good source to learn different combinations for different cases? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks very much @RamRaider